# Раздел языкознания

Tags: лингвистика

И вопрос вдогонку, возникший, пока писала о Красной (или красной?) горке.
А вопрос возник о том, какой тэг ставить - к какому разделу языкознания его отнести. Этимология, вроде как, занимается происхождением только отдельных слов, а тут словосочетание. А фразеология - значением устойчивых оборотов речи, к которым это словосочетание тоже не отнесешь.
Как вы думаете, какой раздел сюда ближе: этимология или фразеология?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Этимология, вроде как, занимается происхождением только отдельных слов

Нет. Сочетаний тоже. А о каком сочетании речь? Если о "Красной горке" - то вполне годится по крайней мере в одном значении. Это народное название праздника Антипасхи.

Answer (score 1):

В затруднительных ситуациях, всегда выбираю "общие вопросы", это помогает избежать использования заведомо неправильных тэгов.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, наука, изучающая географические названия называется **топонимика**. Учитывая, что вопросы, про происхождение наименования того или иного объекта на карте периодически возникают, метка *топонимика* или *топоним* вполне жизнеспособна.